User name is not showing in answers
In a recent question, two new users have written their answers, but the user name does not show up in the bottom of either of the answer, as illustrated by the screenshot below. Is this a bug or is there some setting that I'm missing? This is the first time I see it happen for a user account that is still in active use.

Here is the corresponding inspection result in Chrome, showing that the name is really empty, not just invisible due to low contrast or anything.

Here is the inspection result for a normal signature.


Both answerers also have no answers, if the timeline is to be believed

Timelines for both answers, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79116308/timeline and https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79116333/timeline

It seems to be back to normal. There must have been a cache problem.

" Is this a bug or is there some setting that I'm missing?" - Why would we ever need a setting to hide user account details under answers :) Rather than "bug" (very little chance you are the one to first spot and report such a visible one) I would nowadays more suspect its fallout from live updates/experiments. Temporary glitches in the matrix are not uncommon.

@Gimby. Temporary glitches in the matrix, Deja Vu?
